# Ajax no funciona correctamente

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

Estoy intentando guardar datos que se encuentran en un form, en la base de datos.

Es un form bastante largo, que contienen varios inputs type text y varios type file.

Mi problema es que no recibo los datos del form al controller.

Hice un `$posted = $this->input->post();   var_dump($posted);`

Pero èste me devuelve `array(0) {}`

En mi form valido los datos con la libreria Jquery Validate. Asique sin mas preambulos, este es mi ajax:

```
$.validator.setDefaults( {
    submitHandler: function() {
      if ($('input[name="tipobeca"]:checked').length == 0) {
         alert('Por favor selecciona el tipo de beca');
         return false; }
          else {

              $.ajax({
                  url: baseUrl  + "Solicitud/enviardatos/",
                  method : "POST",
                  data : $("#formvalidate").serialize(),
                  async: false,
                  beforeSend:function(){
                  jQuery('#ajaxloading').show();
                   $('.loader').show();
                   alert("espera....");
                  },
                   success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data=="ok"){
                      alert(baseUrl + "Solicitud/enviardatos/");
                      window.location.href = baseUrl + "Solicitudok/";
                      $('.loader').hide();
                      jQuery('#ajaxloading').hide();
                    }
                    alert("entro al success pero error");

                   },
                   error:function(data){
                     $('.loader').hide();
                     jQuery('#ajaxloading').hide();
                     alert("error");
                   },
                   cache: false,
                   contentType: false,
                   processData: false
                 });
       }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
       $(element).closest(".form-group" ).addClass( "has-error" ).removeClass( "has-success" );
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
       $(element).closest(".form-group" ).removeClass( "has-success" ).removeClass( "has-error" );
    },


 });
```

Teniendo un cuenta el var_dump mencionado anteriormente, el problema debe estar en ese codigo. Asique momentaneamente dejo el post hasta aca.

**EDIT**

Con el `alert($("#formvalidate").serialize())` me sale esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los **inputs** del **table** tienen una cadena de texto rara. Por las dudas, pongo como tomo los datos de los inputs del table (que estan dentro del form).

```
//ASIGNAMOS VARIABLES A LOS ARREGLOS DEL TABLE GRUPO FAMILIAR.
            $items1 = ($_POST['nombre']);
            $items2 = ($_POST['apellido']);
            $items3 = ($_POST['vinculo']);
            $items4 = ($_POST['ocupacion']);
            var_dump($items1);

            // Estas variables son siempre iguales
            // No tiene sentido definirlas en el ciclo
            $dni = $_POST['dni'];
            $fecha = date("Y-m-d");

              // Antes de comenzar la subida "respaldas" $_FILES
              $files = $_FILES;
            // Recorrer con ciclo for
            for($i = 0; $i < count($items1); $i++) {
                // Usar el mismo índice para acceder a todos los elementos
                $item1 = $items1[$i];
                $item2 = $items2[$i];
                $item3 = $items3[$i];
                $item4 = $items4[$i];

                // Asignar el archivo actual a $_FILES
                 $_FILES['ingreso']['name'] = $files['ingreso']['name'][$i];
                 $_FILES['ingreso']['type'] = $files['ingreso']['type'][$i];
                 $_FILES['ingreso']['tmp_name'] = $files['ingreso']['tmp_name'][$i];
                 $_FILES['ingreso']['error'] = $files['ingreso']['error'][$i];
                 $_FILES['ingreso']['size'] = $files['ingreso']['size'][$i];

                $rand = rand(1,1000000);


                $nombre = "ingrFliarN°$dni-$fecha-$rand-";

                $vinput = "";
                $vinput = 'ingreso' . ($i + 1);
                //POR CADA ITERACION CARGA EN LA BASE DE DATOS EL GRUPO FAMILIAR.
                $this->cargar_archivosgrupofamiliar($item1, $item2, $item3, $item4, 'ingreso', $nombre);
          }
```

Comment: debes de poner la ruta completa `Solicitud/enviardatos/archivo.php`

Comment: @Christian Hola como andas? Es Codeigniter, y la ruta es un controller.

Comment: Lo siento no lo había tomado en cuenta

Comment: Tal vez deberías dar una mirada a qué estás especificando como datos que debe utilizar *ajax* en el POST. `data : $("#formvalidate").serialize()` ¿Qué hay en `$("#formvalidate")`? Prueba `alert($("#formvalidate").serialize())` antes de  `$.ajax`.

Comment: @V.Lorz hola como andas? Ahí edite la publicación.

Comment: @V.Lorz También hice un **alert($("#formvalidate").serializeArray())** y devuelve ['object']

Comment: Los inputs del table tienen el   name="nombre[]"  por eso en el alert sale nombre%5B%EB

Comment: Y si tomo las variables una por una y las paso mediante el data en $.ajax ???

Comment: Puedes crear un objeto JSON con los datos que necesitas pasar al servidor y utilizarlo en el campo `data` que pasas a *ajax*. Es necesario que especifiques `dataType : 'json'`. Ese será el contenido del POST. Luego en el servidor lo deserializas.

Comment: @V.Lorz Como seria???

Comment: Por que como harias para tomar los inputs name="nombre[]"

Comment: Además. ahora que observo bien, no me toma los inputs type file.

Comment: Tal vez puedas dar un vistazo a [esto](https://cybmeta.com/ajax-con-json-y-php-ejemplo-paso-a-paso). Hay ejemplos que te ayudarán.

Comment: No pude solucionarlo...